# Middle of the Linked List

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

In the code below, when using two pointers technique, it's confusing that why we use slow.next and fast.next.next. For example in the linked list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], if we are in the last position '10' (fast pointer), the slow pointer should be in the '8' position. Could someone please clarify that?

```
def middleNode(self, head):
        slow = fast = head 
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
            
        return slow
```

Comment: If two people start at the same spot, and one takes two steps when the other only takes one. If they have crossed a mile like that, do you really think the slower person will be just 2 steps behind the faster one?

Comment: Your reasoning seems to assume that `slow.next == fast.next` at each iteration. That's only true for the *first* iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In short:* `fast` moves at **double** speed of `slow`. Their distance increases at each iteration by one. This is different than moving with the same velocity but starting different positions (say one starts at 0 and the other at 2).

More detailed explanation:

The `fast` pointer moves with double the speed of the slow pointer, that's why when the `fast` pointer reaches the end of the linked list, the `slow` pointer is in the middle. That's the reason why the `fast` pointer moves `fast.next.next`. This means that `fast` skips one and jumps 2 fields in each iteration, while the `slow` pointer only moves one. That's also the reason you check `fast and fast.next` in the `while` loop condition, to make sure the `next` pointer is not `None`, because you want to call `next` on it.

Let's take a smaller example then you have provided to make illustration easier:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]

# before entering the while loop:
# head is at position 1
# fast and slow both are at position 1

# first iteration
[1,2,3,4,5]
 f
 s
fast == 1 and fast.next == 2
slow == 1
fast jumps 2 nodes and becomes 3 (fast.next.next)
slow jumps 1 node and becomes 2 (slow.next)

# second iteration
[1,2,3,4,5]
     f
   s
fast == 3 and fast.next == 4
slow == 2
fast jumps 2 nodes and becomes 5 (fast.next.next)
slow jumps 1 node and becomes 3 (slow.next)

# third iteration (doesn't enter the loop, see why)
[1,2,3,4,5]
         f
     s
fast == 5 and fast.next == None (tail of linked list)
slow == 3
# while loop breaks
# we return slow which lies in the middle of the linked list
```