# Why Two Pointer Algorithm Works ?( slow and fast pointer technique)

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

i'm learning data structure and algorithm . and learnt about two pointer algorithm . i learnt how it works and how to implement it.

But don't quite understand why it works ? ( i.e slow and fast pointer approach )

when finding middle node in a linked list . when the fast pointer reaches the end , the slow pointer points to middle node . why though ?

I'm really curious !!

i'm trying to understand

Comment: If 2*N = length(list), what is N?

Comment: If you have two people running a track of 100m, and one runs twice as fast as the other, then where will the slower one be at when the fast person crosses the 100m mark?

Comment: If there is a loop, the fast pointer will never reach the end.  It will keep going until it catches up to the slow pointer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396261/middle-of-the-linked-list I hope this give you the answer

Comment: I realize now that I misunderstood the question, so my first comment probably didn't make much sense.  Usually the slow/fast pointer technique is used to detect a linked list with a loop in it, but that has nothing to do with what you asked.